# Does $(a,b,1)$ lie on a line or a plane?

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, contest-math, 3d

The following question is taken from Cengage book by G.Tiwani. This book is used for the preparation of IIT-JEE exam.

**Question**:

A function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined as $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ax^2+bx+c+e^{nx}}{1+ce^{nx}},$$ where $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ then

(A) points $(a,b,c)$ lie on a line in the 3-dimensional coordinate system.

(B) points $(a,b)$ represent the 2-dimensional Cartesian plane

(C) locus of points $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ intersect at one point.

(D) points $(a,b,c)$ lie on a plane in the 3-dimensional coordinate system.

**My Attempt:**

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} ax^2+bx+c;& x\lt0 \\ \frac{c+1}{1+c};&x=0 \\ \frac1c;&x\gt0\end{cases}$$

Therefore, $c=1, a, b \in \mathbb R$

So, I think the options B,D are correct.

But the answer given is A,B,C.

How to approach this?

Comment: Just a note, but I think $c=-1$ is also a possible solution, with $f(0)=-1$

Comment: @Andrei but isn't $f(0)$ only equal to $1$?

Comment: $(1+c)/(1+c)=1$ only if $c\ne -1$. IN the limit $x\to 0$ you get $$f(x)\to\frac{ax^2+bx+c+1-nx+...}{1+c+cnx+...}$$If $c=-1$ you get $$\lim_{n\to \infty,x\to 0}\frac{(b+n)x+..}{(-1)nx+...}=-1$$

Comment: @Andrei thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, starting from your attempt we have 2 cases

- $c\neq -1$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} ax^2+bx+c;& x\lt0 \\ \frac{c+1}{1+c};&x=0 \\ \frac1c;&x\gt0\end{cases} \implies c=1,\ f(x)=\begin{cases} ax^2+bx+1;& x\lt0 \\ 1;&x\ge0\end{cases}$$

- $c= -1$

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} ax^2+bx-1;& x\lt0 \\ -1;&x\ge0\end{cases}$$

So it seems that $(B)$ is always true and $(C)$, $(D)$ are also true but only separately for each case with $c=1$ and $c=-1$.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain how C) is true?

Comment: @aarbee Let consider $c=1$ then $(a,1)$ and $(1,b)$ represent two lines intersecting at $(1,1)$. For $c=-1$ then $(a,-1)$ and $(-1,b)$ represent two lines intersecting at $(-1,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks, one last doubt. The answer given is ABC. That's incorrect, right? $(a,b,1)$ or $(a,b,-1)$ are planes, not lines, right?

Comment: @aarbee Yes it seems the given solutions is wrong for a typo.

Comment: Thanks, I'll award the bounty in a few days.

Comment: @aarbee You are welcome. I hope we can have some other answer. I would say that only $(B)$ is correct because we have $2$ possible value for $c$.